# Javascript: Printing class attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class-attributes

I got a class in css :

```
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

and an img in the HTML body. I can move the img with my JQuery/Javascript code:

```
 $('img').animate({left: "-=20"}, 'fast');
```

Now I want to print out the attribute 'left' from my img class. Any Suggestions how to do that? My `window.alert($('img').left)` does not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a certain css attribute, use

```
$('foo').css('bar', '42');
```

To access a certain css attribute, use

```
$('foo').css('bar');
```

Thus, to answer your question:

```
window.alert($('img').css('left'));
```

To learn more:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helps me out very well

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer that was helpful

Comment: Done. By the way I got another question. Whats the difference between .css and .animate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to read the style.

I suppose that you want to get the position after the animation has completed:

```
$('img').animate({left: "+=20"}, 'fast', function(){
  window.alert($('img').css('left'));
});
```